# Why Stanford parser with nltk is not correctly parsing a sentence?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford parser with nltk in python and got help from [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk)  to set up Stanford nlp libraries.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
parser     = StanfordParser(model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
dep_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
one = ("John sees Bill")
parsed_Sentence = parser.raw_parse(one)
# GUI
for line in parsed_Sentence:
       print line
       line.draw()

parsed_Sentence = [parse.tree() for parse in dep_parser.raw_parse(one)]
print parsed_Sentence

# GUI
for line in parsed_Sentence:
        print line
        line.draw()
```

I am getting wrong parse and dependency trees as shown in the example below, it is treating 'sees' as noun instead of verb.

[image: Example parse tree]
[image: Example dependency tree]

What should I do?
It work perfectly right when I change sentence e.g.(one = 'John see Bill').
The correct ouput for this sentence can be viewed from here [correct ouput of parse tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401076/difference-between-constituency-parser-and-dependency-parser)

Example of correct output is also shown below:

[image: correctly parsed]

[image: correct dependency parsed tree]

Comment: Please post the full code snippet so that other understands where `dep_parser` comes from =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once again, no model is perfect (see [Python NLTK pos_tag not returning the correct part-of-speech tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag)) ;P

You can try a "more accurate" parser, using the `NeuralDependencyParser`.

First setup the parser properly with the correct environment variables (see [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/34112695#34112695) and https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a), then:

```
>>> from nltk.internals import find_jars_within_path
>>> from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordNeuralDependencyParser
>>> parser = StanfordNeuralDependencyParser(model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz")
>>> stanford_dir = parser._classpath[0].rpartition('/')[0]
>>> slf4j_jar = stanford_dir + '/slf4j-api.jar'
>>> parser._classpath = list(parser._classpath) + [slf4j_jar]
>>> parser.java_options = '-mx5000m'
>>> sent = "John sees Bill"
>>> [parse.tree() for parse in parser.raw_parse(sent)]
[Tree('sees', ['John', 'Bill'])]
```

Do note that the `NeuralDependencyParser` only produces the dependency trees:

[image]

Comment: I am using model "englishPCFG.ser.gz"  and you are using model "english_UD.gz" . But, how can we choose these models, so that we get able to pick the right one?

Comment: There's no perfect model, there's no right/wrong one too, just the one that fits best to your data. So I would say, try all of them and then evaluate them base on what the ultimate purpose of the parses are for.

Comment: Please follow the instructions till the end on https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a

Comment: i am trying your code and it is taking very long to execute,... 
 
does it take time in execution???

Comment: Follow the last snippet on https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a  that says "Since the CoreNLP can take a while to load all the models before parsing, it's best to use `raw_parse_sents` instead of `raw_parse` when parsing more than one sentence" ;P